# Continuous function with two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Prove that if f:$\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ meets:

$\forall y_0 $ $x \rightarrow f(x,y_0)$ is continuous and increasing

$\forall x_0 $ $y \rightarrow f(x_0,y)$ is continuous

then f is continuous.

Comment: You should try posting what you have tried... It helps you improve your proof-writing, helps us on how we can explain it to you and helps people with the same problem as you in the future... Even the ideas you had help a lot.

Comment: I've tried Cauchy's definition and made some inequalities. But it didn't give me anything...

Comment: I also did this...but there is a problem with first of those 4 terms... $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |f(x_n , y_n) - f(x_p , y_p)| = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |f(x_n , y_n) - f(x_n , y_p) + f(x_n , y_p) - f(x_p , y_p) + f(x_p , y_p) - f(x_p , y_n) + f(x_p , y_n) - f(x_p , y_p)| \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |f(x_n , y_n) - f(x_n , y_p)| + |f(x_n , y_p) - f(x_p , y_p)| + |f(x_p , y_p) - f(x_p , y_n)| + |f(x_p , y_n) - f(x_p , y_p)|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $(x_0,y_0)$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|x-x_0| \le \delta_1$ implies that $|f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)| \le \epsilon/2$. Similarly, there exists a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $|y - y_0| \le \delta_2$ implies that $|f(x_0+\delta_1,y)-f(x_0+\delta_1,y_0)| \le \epsilon/2$ and $|f(x_0-\delta_1,y)-f(x_0-\delta_1,y_0)| \le \epsilon/2$. It follows that for all $x$ and $y$ such that $|x-x_0| \le \delta_1$ and $|y-y_0| \le \delta_2$, 
\begin{align}
f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) 
& \le f(x_0+\delta_1,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \quad \mbox{(because $f(\cdot,y)$ is increasing)}\\
& \le |f(x_0+\delta_1,y) - f(x_0+\delta_1,y_0)| + |f(x_0+\delta_1,y_0) - f(x_0,y_0)| \\ 
& \le \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) 
& \ge f(x_0-\delta_1,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \quad \mbox{(because $f(\cdot,y)$ is increasing)}\\
& \ge -|f(x_0-\delta_1,y) - f(x_0-\delta_1,y_0)| - |f(x_0-\delta_1,y_0) - f(x_0,y_0)| \\ 
& \ge -\epsilon/2 - \epsilon/2 = -\epsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: Great. It would help to add a phrase to indicate precisely where you're using the hypothesis that $f(x,y)$ is increasing for fixed $y$.

Comment: Is this $-\epsilon/2-\epsilon/2 = \epsilon$ a typo or just I can't get it?

Comment: I added the node. Is that ok?

Comment: Fine now. Great ;)

Comment: Fixed the $\epsilon$ to $-\epsilon$. Sorry for the typo.